# package.json script ignoring NODE_ENV value for production only

Tags: javascript, node.js, jenkins, webpack

I have a series of Jenkinsfiles that looks like this (this is the production version):

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        dockerfile {
            filename 'Dockerfile'
            dir 'jenkins/'
            label 'agent && linux'
            args '''
                -v /var/lib/package-cache/.npm:/.npm:rw,z
            '''
        }
    }
    environment {
        NODE_ENV = "production"
    }
    stages {
        stage('Install dependencies') {
            steps {
                sh "npm ci --production=false"
                sh "npx cypress install"
                sh "npm install -g cross-env"
            }
        }
        stage('Cypress tests') {
            parallel {
                stage('Start local server') {
                    steps {
                        sh returnStatus: true, script: "npm run start:test"
                    }
                }
                stage('Run Cypress tests') {
                    steps {
                        sh 'npm run wait'
                        sh 'cross-env NODE_ENV=test npm run cypress:run'
                        sh 'killall node'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh "npm run build:${NODE_ENV}"
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                sh "npm run publish:${NODE_ENV}"
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        always {
            echo "Job completed"
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the versions for the Jenkinsfile for the other environments use that particular environment (development, qa, and staging) for the `NODE_ENV = "{ENV}"` line.

The scripts in my `package.json` includes the following:

```
{
    "start": "cross-env TS_NODE_PROJECT=\"tsconfig-for-webpack-config.json\" webpack-dev-server --http --port 9003",
    "start:development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development npm run start",
    "start:test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test npm run start",
    "start:qa": "cross-env NODE_ENV=qa npm run start",
    "start:staging": "cross-env NODE_ENV=staging npm run start",
    "start:production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production npm run start",
    "cypress:run": "cypress run",
  },
```

In all non-production environments, the `npm run start:test` line in the Jenkinsfile correctly uses `test` for `NODE_ENV` when webpack dev server starts.  When the production Jenkinsfile is used, however, it ends up using `production` for `NODE_ENV` rather than `test` when `npm run start:test` is called.

**What would be causing my `npm run start:test` script to be ignoring the value (of `test`) I'm setting via `cross-env` and, instead, using `production`?**

Comment: Which OS you are using?

Comment: @RichardRublev The Jenkins jobs are running on a Linux box.

Comment: It seems that NODE_ENV is not recognized. Do you have env config files?

Comment: @RichardRublev I have a config/config file for each environment that is selected in my webpack.config based off the NODE_ENV.  To be clear, this works correctly for all other environments, just not production.